# AngularJs ng-enter animation affects positioning of footer

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have an angularjs website composed like this:

[image: image 1]
When a person clicks on slide 2...the ng-view partial animates...i.e swipes left to reveal slide 2 partial.

It's very similar to this:

[Slide Code demo](http://dfsq.github.io/ngView-animation-effects/app/#/code) This works great.
However doing so...makes the **separate footer partial move upwards.**

So it then looks like this after the animation and stays there:

[image: image 2]

I believe this is due to css positioning of the animation.  I've fiddled around but can't get the footer to stay down AFTER the animation.  I don't want the footer to be affected by the animation.
I don't want the footer to be fixed.  If I remove the animation..the footer is situated where I want it to be.

Thanks.

```
.slide {
  position:relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
.slide.ng-enter,
.slide.ng-leave {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
.slide.ng-enter {
    left: 100%;
}
.slide.ng-enter-active {
    left: 0;
}
.slide.ng-leave {
    left: 0;
}
.slide.ng-leave-active {
    left: -100%;
}
```

and this is the footer css

```
.oilFooter {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30%;
    background-color: #1c1c1c;
    position:relative;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try wrap your ng-view in div and set height of div via directive.

Html:

```
<div data-ng-include="'/app/menu/menu.html'"></div>
<div>
    <div resizable ng-view></div>
</div>
<div data-ng-include="'/app/footer/footer.html'"></div>
```

Directive:

```
function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        var parent = element.parent();
        scope.$watch(function () { return element.height() }, function (newValue, oldValue) {
            parent.css('height', newValue);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Working off @zooblin's answer, If you have enough content for your ng-view to cover a height of 1200px, simply add `min-height: 1200px;` to your ng-view.

Answer (score 0):

don't know if you still search for an answer, but here is what I did.

Instead of using pure CSS I started using JavaScript for animation. Here is the Code:

```js
this.App.animation('.view-slide-in', function () {
  return {
    enter: function (element, done) {
      element.css({
        opacity: 0
      })
      .animate({
        opacity: 1
      }, 500, done);
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<div class="view-slide-in" ui-view="main" autoscroll="false"></div>
```

This seems to work for me. :-) But I haven't try more complex animation yet because I only wanted something simple.